# JMC Flight Recorder is not working

Tags: jmc

I **Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)** deployed on Linux box. I am able to run Java Mission control (JMC) however I am not able to run "Flight Recorder" from the JMC. I am getting a popup with this message :

*Commercial features are not enabled. In JDK7u4 and above, the JVM must be started with -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder.*

I checked my jmc.ini file which resides in the same $JAVA_HOME/bin directory as JMC application itself and it has these two flags :

-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder

What could be the problem with the Flight Recorder?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those parameters you need to add to the JVM you wish to start recordings on. (They are already added for JMC itself, since we want people to be able to record the JMC client, should it be needed for support reasons. As a matter of fact, more recent versions of the JMC are always starting with a recording running. That way, even if the JVM crashes, there is always information about what was going on in the runtime.)

Simply add the parameters to the start-up of the JVM you wish to do recordings on. Here is more info:
http://hirt.se/blog/?p=370

Answer (score 0):

If it fails to connect to the JMC application itself, it's strange. Otherwise, you must add the command line parameters to JVM you want to monitor.

Comment: What parameters should I add to the JVM I may monitor?

Comment: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder